# Android - getSupportedPreviewSizes only returns Landscape sizes

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-camera

I am trying to build a Live feature similar to Instagram Live. And I want to open the camera preview full screen in portrait mode. I am using the below to set the size of the preview of the camera. But I am only getting stretched and distorted scales.

**Reason being that getSupportedPreviewSizes from which we choose the optimal resolution to be used, is only returning landscape sizes and not portrait ones (Width > Height).**

**Any idea how to make *getSupportedPreviewSizes()* return Supported Portrait sizes instead ?**

```
 public int[] setPreviewResolution(int width, int height) {                
        mCamera = openCamera();
        
        mPreviewWidth = width;
        mPreviewHeight = height;
        Camera.Size rs = adaptPreviewResolution(mCamera.new Size(width, height));
        if (rs != null) {
            mPreviewWidth = rs.width;
            mPreviewHeight = rs.height;
        }
        
        getHolder().setFixedSize(mPreviewWidth, mPreviewHeight);
        
        mCamera.getParameters().setPreviewSize(mPreviewWidth, mPreviewHeight);

        mGLPreviewBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(mPreviewWidth  mPreviewHeight  4);
        mInputAspectRatio = mPreviewWidth > mPreviewHeight ?
            (float) mPreviewWidth / mPreviewHeight : (float) mPreviewHeight / mPreviewWidth;

        return new int[] { mPreviewWidth, mPreviewHeight };
    }




    private Camera.Size adaptPreviewResolution(Camera.Size resolution) {
            float diff = 100f;
            float xdy = (float) resolution.width / (float) resolution.height;
            Camera.Size best = null;
            for (Camera.Size size : mCamera.getParameters().getSupportedPreviewSizes()) {
                Log.v("widthhhhhhhhhhhdddd supported","" +" size.width: "+size.width+"   hhhh: "+size.height);
                if (size.equals(resolution)) {
                    return size;
                }
                float tmp = Math.abs(((float) size.height / (float) size.width) - xdy);
                if (tmp < diff) {
                    diff = tmp;
                    best = size;
                }
    
            }
    
            return best;
        }
```

Answer (score -1):

1. Get the supported preview sizes using the `getSupportedPreviewSizes()` method.
2. Find the preview size that has a height greater than its width. This will be the portrait mode size.
3. Set the preview size to this portrait mode size and use `setRotation(90)` to rotate the preview.
4. To make the preview full screen, set the layout parameters of the `SurfaceView` or `TextureView` that you are using to display the camera preview to fill the parent.

Here is an example:

```
CameraManager cameraManager = (CameraManager) getSystemService(Context.CAMERA_SERVICE);
String cameraId = "0"; // Choose the desired camera ID
CameraCharacteristics characteristics = cameraManager.getCameraCharacteristics(cameraId);
StreamConfigurationMap configMap = characteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.SCALER_STREAM_CONFIGURATION_MAP);
Size[] sizes = configMap.getOutputSizes(SurfaceTexture.class);
Size portraitSize = null;

for (Size size : sizes) {
 if (size.getHeight() > size.getWidth()) {
    portraitSize = size;
    break;
  }
}

if (portraitSize != null) {
  previewSize = portraitSize;
  int rotation = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getRotation();
  int sensorOrientation = characteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.SENSOR_ORIENTATION);
  int deviceRotation = ORIENTATIONS.get(rotation);
  int totalRotation = (sensorOrientation + deviceRotation + 360) % 360;
  previewRequestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.JPEG_ORIENTATION, totalRotation);
}
SurfaceView surfaceView = findViewById(R.id.camera_preview);
surfaceView.setLayoutParams(new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
```

Comment: My issue precisely is that the getSupportedPreviewSizes() is returning only landscape ratios, not portrait. I need to get the best supported portrait size to fit the screen of the user.